# Mysql query with group by gives empty result in specific column

Tags: mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT value_bezoeken as sum_bezoeken, value_verkocht as sum_verkocht, postal, month, year, type FROM results WHERE admin_user_id = 1 GROUP BY month, year, postal
```

The mysql table: [Table results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1a7Y.png)

Results after query: [Results after running query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVyyT.png)

It seems that mysql only look at type = bezoeken and not type = verkocht

Why is the column sum_verkocht empty?

Comment: Why do you use group by if you are not doing any aggregation?

Comment: I changed my post and second image. I added the column type also to the query and it seems that mysql only looks at type=bezoeken instead of bezoeken and verkocht

Comment: guess you actually needs `SUM(value_bezoeken)` and `SUM(value_verkocht)`

Comment: Yes that's it. Correct!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post images of data and/or code. Copy the data to the post instead. See also [ask] and how to add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ProGu for the correct answer.

I changed my query to `SELECT SUM(value_bezoeken) as sum_bezoeken, SUM(value_verkocht) as sum_verkocht, postal, month, year, type FROM results WHERE admin_user_id = 1 GROUP BY month, year, postal`